# Split XML based on size using Java

Tags: java, xml, filesplitting

I am trying to split an XML file using the following method, it created the first split file no problem but when i use output.clear(); to clear the Array of XMLEvents that already have been written it throws an error.

error: Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: No element was found to write: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

i tried to investigate this issue with no success, any advice on what is causing the error or how to overcome it greatly appreciated!

```
public void SplitBySize() throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException, IOException {

    //File Path
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\thamm\\Desktop\\XMLFile\\Data2.xml";

    //Read XML file.
    Reader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);

    //Get XMLInputFactory instance.
    XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

    //Create XMLEventReader object.
    XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(fileReader);

    long charCount = 0;
    int fileNumber = 1;

    while (xmlEventReader.hasNext()) {

        XMLEvent event = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
        charCount++;
        output.add(event);

        if (charCount == MAX_SIZE) {

            XMLEventWriter xmlEventWriter = factory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\thamm\\Desktop\\SplitFiles\\output_part_" + fileNumber + ".xml"));

            for (XMLEvent i : output) {
                xmlEventWriter.add(i);
            }

            xmlEventWriter.close();
            output.clear();
            charCount = 0;
            fileNumber++;

        }

        if (event.isEndDocument()) {

            XMLEventWriter xmlEventWriter = factory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\thamm\\Desktop\\SplitFiles\\output_part_End.xml"));

            for (XMLEvent i : output) {
                xmlEventWriter.add(i);
            }
            xmlEventWriter.close();
            output.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `output` is a `List` defined in your class, I think your problem is that you use `output.clear()` twice.

The first time, you use `output.clear()` is OK because you add an element before.

```
output.add(event);
```

But the second time, `output` is empty.

**Solution**

- You need to check if `output` is empty before using `output.clear()` with something like `output.isEmpty()`
- You maybe forgot to add elements into your list before clearing it.

Comment: Hi Mickaël, thanks for you reply .. i have debugged the program to see if the output is empty on the second loop but its is successfully cleared and XMLEvents are being added again.

Comment: What is the line that causing the exception ?

Comment: for (XMLEvent i : output) {
xmlEventWriter.add(i);
}   The problem seems to be here .. i have added xmlWriter.flush(); to see each output as i debug and the program begins to output The Elements to the second file but then the error is thrown after 2 elements are outputted and the program terminates